# Функция не инкрементирует переменную

Tags: php

Коллеги, добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, почему вызов функции не инкрементирует переменную? Пробовал и префиксный, и постфиксный, не хочет...

```
<?php

function plusone($name)
{
    ++$name;
}

$variable_one = 5;

plusone($variable_one);

echo $variable_one;

?>
```

Comment: Поставьте `echo $name` в функции после инкрементации и увидите магию :) Вы не меняете переменную, вы передаете ее значение в функцию, но результат работы фукнции не возвращаете. Само значение переменной как было, так и осталась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо SwaD, я вспомнил) Можно просто в объявлении функции в параметр передавать переменную по ссылке, и тогда все заработает)

Делается это вот так

```
function plusone(&$name)
{
    ++$name;
}
```